# Создание Dll в Dev-C++

Tags: c, dll

Зачем нужны приведенные ниже строки при создании dll-ки в Dev-C++. С ними и без них все работает, и функции из созданной библиотеки вызываются из Python. Кто-то может развернуто пояснить, что и зачем?
Ответ про точку вхождения и что-то непонятное далее мне не понравилось. И почему я могу просто удалить .h  файл из проекта, и все опять же компилиться и работает.

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HINSTANCE hInst     /* Library instance handle. */ ,
                       DWORD reason        /* Reason this function is being called. */ ,
                       LPVOID reserved     /* Not used. */ )
{
    switch (reason)
    {
      case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        break;

      case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;

      case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;

      case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    /* Returns TRUE on success, FALSE on failure */
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: dllку пишу на чистом C

Comment: Вы поставили взаимоисключающие условия. Это действительно точка входа DLL, если не хотите подробности узнать - просто игнорируйте.

Comment: Мне интресено на что это влияет, и чего не будет, если я эти строчки кильну.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта функция (DllMain) вызывается **системой** при подключении dll к процессу и отключении от него.

Подробно описана [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

Прочтите, что конкретно не понятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: Написано сложновато для меня, но суть ясна, и если вам не трудно, можете указать, чего именно я лишусь, если удалю эти строчки. (просто чтобы мой английски не случился виной моему непониманию)

Comment: Если функции Вашей библиотеки не требуют (по логике задачи)  инициализации (динамической) при загрузке библиотеки или подключении нового потока, то смело выбрасывайте.

Судя по Вашему замечанию в вопросе

    С ними и без них все работает

можете выбросить.

Comment: А вообще -- читайте Петцольда. Более других популяризаторов winapi и win32api что-то и в голову не приходит.

Comment: To ShestakoffVS. 
Вот один из примеров зачем это нужно. Представьте что в начале работы Вашей DLL необходимо распределить динамическую память (malloc()), а при завершении работы эту память нужно освободить (free()). В этом случае Вы можете при вызове DllMain и значением параметра reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH распределить память, а при вызове DllMain с параметром reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH освободить эту память.

Comment: Ага, то есть, если я правильно понял, это возможные реакции на события связанные с dllкой, типа клика мыши в гуе и реакции на это, только с поправкой на те события, которые могут произойти с dllкой. Тогда еще вопрос, если я пишу библиотеку функций OPENGL для того, чтобы вызывать их из питона, могут ли понадобиться какие-то из таких возможных событий (понимаю, что весьма расплывчато звучит вопрос)?